# Cannon js distance constraint not moving second body

Tags: cannon.js

I am experimenting with Cannon JS. I got two bodies created and placed in the world. Then I created a distance constraint with the default of these two body's distance as distance. I put applyLocalImpulse of the body one and was expecting the second one will move alone with the first one like a train. However, the first one moved on its own and the second body stay stationary. Am I getting the idea wrong about the constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I forgot to put the constraint into the world. After that it worked